# Decorator function is not working as expected

Tags: python-decorators

I was doing some testing with imports, and I wanted to test how fast certain packages get imported using function decorators. Here is my code:

```
import time


def timeit(func):
    def wrapper():
        start = time.time()
        func()
        end = time.time()
        print(f'{func.__name__} executed in {end - start} second(s)')
    return wrapper


@timeit
def import_matplotlib():
    import matplotlib.pyplot


@timeit
def import_numpy():
    import numpy


import_matplotlib()
import_numpy()
```

#### Output

```
import_matplotlib executed in 0.4385249614715576 second(s)
import_numpy executed in 0.0 second(s)
```

This is not the expected output given that numpy isn't imported in an instant. What is happening here, and how can this be fixed? Thank you.

## Edit

If I make this change to import_numpy():

```
@timeit
def import_numpy():
    import numpy
    time.sleep(2)
```

The output becomes this:

```
import_matplotlib executed in 0.4556155204772949 second(s)
import_numpy executed in 2.0041260719299316 second(s)
```

This tells me that there isn't anything wrong with my decorator function. Why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: your (initial) code works fine on my machine: `import_numpy executed in 1.1920928955078125e-06 second(s)`. But yeah, importing numpy is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)? It was built for this purpose and makes that code simpler.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='import numpy')
0.13844075199995132
```

Comment: I didn't realize numpy was just importing that fast. I know about the timeit module, but I was just doing this for learning purposes. I have never have worked with decorators before. But your answer raises a big question. How come the value of using the timeit module is much larger than the value generated from my code?